# Resize to 224×224 directly or resize to 256 ×256 then crop 224×224？

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, pytorch, artificial-intelligence

My images in training set are leaves like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9RkM.png)

Its size is 572*108 and my resnet network need 224×224 images as input.
I found most of the codes process the images with the second way(resize to 256 ×256 then crop 224×224) so I did that.
As a result,parts of my leaves were cut which may influence the effect of leaves classification.Like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsyLU.png)

The first way (resize to 256×256 directly) may keep more complete structure.Like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smATt.png)

I am worrying that if choose the first way I will lose many training images since random crop 224×224 may generate more samples for training.

Which should I choose？

Comment: Not all applications are the same, and so not all applications should use the same preprocessing, network structure, etc etc. If having the full outline is important to recognize the leave, don’t crop. If the aspect ratio is important, scale with a fixed aspect ratio. If the size is important, don’t scale. You can always pad your images to make them have the right size.

Comment: cropping *that picture* would be bad because you remove data. -- resizing *without maintaining aspect ratio* would also be bad. I'd suggest that you pad the pictures to be square (224x224 is square) and resize directly, no cropping.

Answer (score 1):

Running two experiments and compare their evalution results is the simplest solution.

A complete view is not neccessary for model to classify images, so as it to human. On the contrary, learning from cropped image normally can improve the generalization capacity of a model.